# Why the time period cannot depend upon the angular velocity and angular acceleration of the pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, units, dimensional-analysis, degrees-of-freedom

To derive the time period $T$ of a [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) using dimensional analysis it is assumed that it depends upon the mass $m$ of the bob, the length of the string $\ell$, the acceleration due to gravity $g$ and the amplitude $\theta_0$. Then, using dimensional analysis, we find $$T=f(\theta_0)\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}$$ where $f(\theta_0)$ is some unknown dimensionless function the dimensionless parameter $\theta_0$.

**1. How can we a priori rule out that $T$ will not depend on the instantaneous values of angular position $\theta(t)$, angular velocity $\dot{\theta}(t)$ and angular acceleration $\ddot{\theta}(t)$? What forbids $T$ to depend upon both $\dot{\theta}(t)$ and $\ddot{\theta}(t)$ in such a way that the time dependences cancel out?**

2. **If $T$ depends only on the constant values, why not initial velocity $\dot{\theta}(t_0)$ and $\ddot{\theta}(t_0)$?**

I'm trying to argue physically without solving the equation of motion.

Comment: $\theta_0$ is an amplitude that does not (in the undamped case) depend on time while, of course, the angular position $\theta(t)$ *does* depend on time as does $\omega(t) = \dot\theta(t)$ and $\alpha(t) = \ddot\theta(t)$.  Why then did you (1) not ask about dependence on $\omega_0$ and $\alpha_0$ in accord with $\theta_0$ or (2) not ask about $\theta(t)$ in accord with $\omega(t)$ and $\alpha(t)$?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Agreed. I've modifed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wanted to consider a dependence on the amplitude $\dot\theta_0$ of the angular speed and on the amplitude $\ddot\theta_0$ of the angular acceleration, since you can only consider constants as pointed out in @nasu's answer. So let's do that:

$$T = m^\alpha l^\beta g^\gamma \dot\theta_0^\epsilon \ddot\theta_0^\eta.$$

So plugging the dimentions,

$$[T] \propto [M]^\alpha[L]^\beta[LT^{-2}]^\gamma[T^{-1}]^\epsilon[T^{-2}]^\eta,$$

which implies that

$$\begin{align}
\alpha&=0,\\
\beta+\gamma&=0,\\
-2\gamma-\epsilon-2\eta&=1.
\end{align}$$

As you see, you don't have enough equations to nail down all the exponents. The best conclusion you can reach is that

$$T\propto \left(\frac{l}{g}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}+\eta+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon}\dot\theta_0^\epsilon \ddot\theta_0^\eta.$$

You reach the limits of dimensional analysis here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the EOM from Newton's 2nd law is a 2nd order ODE, i.e. it has 2 integration constants, and we have already specified 2 initial conditions: $$\theta(t_0)~=~\theta_0\qquad\text{and}\qquad\dot{\theta}(t_0)~=~0,$$
cf. the definition of the [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude) $\theta_0$.
(It cannot depend on the initial time $t_0$ because of time translation symmetry.)

Comment: What if instead of starting the particle from one of the extreme positions, we set the initial time $t=t_0$ when the particle passes through the equilibrium position $\theta=0$? At that time $\dot{\theta}(t_0)\neq 0$. @Qmechanic

Answer (score 2):

Dimensional analysis seeks to understand relations between *constants* in your problem: these are $m$, $g$, $\ell$ and the initial position $\theta_0$.  The basic idea is that this *constant* captures something “natural” about the system, independent of specific details of the problem.    Since $\dot\theta$ or $\ddot{\theta}$ are not constants, they are not considered.  Thus, the [Planck units](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units), for instance, are constants obtained in term of various fundamental constants of Nature.

One way to understand this is to rephrase your equation as the search for a dimensionless constant quantity $\Pi$ of the form:
$$
\Pi= \frac{T}{f(\theta_0)} \ell^{a}g^b m^d = \frac{T}{f(\theta_0)} \sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}\, . \tag{1}
$$
with $f(\theta_0)$ dimensionless.   Extending (1) to functions of $\dot\theta$ or $\ddot{\theta}$ would imply that $\Pi$ is not a constant, contrary to the basic hypothesis.

Dimensional analysis says nothing about the function $f(\theta_0)$, which must be determined from experiment or from some more detailed theory.  It does tell us that, if you start your pendulum always as $\theta_0$ and increase $\ell$ by $4$ the period $T$ will increase by $2$, which is true irrespective of any other details.

Comment: "_Dimensional analysis seeks to understand relations between constants in your problem_" Is this statement always true? Dimensional analysis can be used to guess Ohm's law $V=IR$ (where $V$ and $I$ are not constants) or Joule heating law $Q\propto I^2Rt$ or Stokes' law of viscosity $F\propto \eta rv$ and many more.

Comment: In $T\sim \sqrt{\ell/g}$, $\ell$ does not vary *in time* and is considered constant, i.e. for some given $\ell$ what is the relation between this $\ell$ the period $T$ and other constants in the problem.  In the example of your ideal resistor, the resistance is considered constant, and you are seeking a functional relation between some constant current, voltage and resistance.